# Can \fp_eval handle uppercase e ("E") exponent symbol format

Tags: expl3, fp

While handling data from a text file, I stumbled upon this problem.

My numeric data is formatted using a `%n.dE` C format specifier. which outputs numbers with a uppercase e (E) as scientific notation exponent character.
While the lowercase e situation works fine, the floating point calculation seems to fail with these major E characters.

I know the best solution would be to symply change the write format specifier, but I think that there is a bug in the generating software, which prevents me to correct this.

I there an option for the `fp` module to correct this ? I can't find the documentation for this.

Here is an example throwing the problematic error

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand \eval { m } { \fp_eval:n { #1 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \eval{123456789}
    \eval{1.23456789}
    \eval{1.23456789e3}
    \eval{1.23456789E3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the question.  The next version of l3fp should allow for uppercase E exponent marker: I've just pushed the change to our code repository.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch That's great, thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can programmatically lowercase the string:

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \eval { m } { \fp_eval:n { \str_lowercase:n { #1 } } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \eval{123456789}
    \eval{1.23456789}
    \eval{1.23456789e3}
    \eval{1.23456789E3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I took the liberty to change `Declare` into `New`: it's preferable, because it checks whether the command is already defined.

Comment: @egreg much appreciated! (I hadn't really look too much at the code to be honest, only copied it over and added the `\str_lowercase:n`)

Comment: As simple as that. Thanks